# Using aspnet_regiis to change the ASP.Net version of a single site on a web server

Tags: c#, iis

We would like to change a web site from version 1.1 to 2.0.50727 during the installation of a solution.

We would prefer a solution that could do this in code.

We can do this by running **Aspnet_regiis -i** . However, this has a drawback that it changes the version for all sites on the server, and the customer may have other sites that we should not change.

Is there a way to do this in code?

Is there a way to run Aspnet_regiis such that it only affects a single site on the web server?

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar question on stackoverflow with an answer that used code:

[IIS 6.0 DirectoryEntry ScriptMaps property and set .Net version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299084/iis-6-0-directoryentry-scriptmaps-property-and-set-net-version)

Answer (score 10):

For a virtual directory use:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis /s W3SVC/1/ROOT/<YourVirtualDirectoryName>
```

Where 1 (W3SVC/**1**/ROOT) is the website id.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to run Aspnet_regiis such that it only affects a single site on the web server?

Yes.

Run `aspnet_regiis -?` and it will list all its options, including how to specify a virtual directory (it will include all child virtual directories as well).